# High CPU Utilization and Server Hung due to Telnet Command

Tags: unix, jboss, telnet, rhel, health-monitoring

High Cpu utilisation caused due to Telnet Command running every 15 minutes on target servers.

We have developed a Health Check Script for the Production Environment to check the service status of various services running on RHEL OS.

The Script Runs every 15 Minutes on Server to Produce Health Report and send email in case of any issue found in system.

**The Script does the below job part of the Health Check and runs every 15 Minutes.

1. Telnet IP: PORT (Where IP/PORT = multiple downstream servers like AppServer, Web Server, DB Server etc to check service status)
2. CURL URL ( App Server URL, Web Server URL, Load Balancer URL etc)**

Our Servers went into Hung state after 4 days of the running script. Our RHEL OS Support Team confirmed that Server CPU Utilization was keeps increasing day by day after running the script and went into HUNG state due to continuous use of the telnet command.

we have already **used the timeout parameter in Telnet Command** to avoid HIGH CPU Utilization. Could you please help me to understand HOW TELNET can make the server in HUNG State and what is the right way to write TELNET command to avoid Sever HIGH CPU Utilization?

Thanks

Comment: What does your script do on the hung target server? Please [edit] your question to explain. Also, try https://serverfault.com/ .

Comment: Do NOT cross post! Delete this one first. It's off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: My question is simple on TELNET command cost and the right way of use in the script. i have read the mentioned link and found my query relevant to this forum.

Comment: Why telnet? I guess they are not telnet servers

Comment: I am doing a telnet to remote servers to check if those remote servers are listening and healthy. However, my telnet sessions are not getting closed by the script and causing HIGH CPU Utilization on remote servers.  I am looking to make a correction in telnet command to close the connection after 5 seconds and not keep it intact with remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem now and working fine with below methods. Please find the answer of my question-

**Option-1** If you are running any Script in bash/unix then adding cleanup method helps to kill any process which is not closed automatically. Code Snippet is below at the end of Script-

```
cleanup_exit(){
pkill -P $$
sleep 1
pkill -9 -P $$
}
trap "cleanup_exit" SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGTERM EXIT
```

**Option-2** If you are looking just to cleanup telnet command process then use below in your script at the end of Script

```
pids = $(ps -ef | grep telnet | awk'{print $2'})
for pid in $pids; do kill -9 $pid
done
```